# Как реализовать постраничный вывод из БД MySQL в Datatables?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, datatable

- дано: БД MySQL, в ней довольно объемная таблица (несколько ГБ)
- необходимо: вывести информацию из БД в Datatables построчно

сейчас я делаю так:

1. на стороне PHP делаю SQL запрос, затем оборачиваю его в
   json_encode() и записываю в определенный файл
2. на самой странице читаю JSON файл и вывожу построчно информацию в таблицу

если строк несколько тысяч, то проблем нет
но в моей таблице миллионы строк, как сделать, чтобы на 1 странице отображалось только 100 строк, при переходе на страницу 2, грузить следующие 100 строк и так далее

саму реализацию постраничной навигации я знаю, не понимаю, как её связать с Datatables

нужно что-то вроде в onclick() на номер страницы повесить ajax-запрос с GET параметром (номером страницы), по которому можно указать в SQL запросе начальный и конечный LIMIT и в JSON выгрузить только нужные строки

примера моего кода нет, т.к. всё стандартно: пример из док-ции datatables и простейший SQL запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о [www.datatables.net](https://www.datatables.net/), то я не понимаю зачем вы записываете json в файл, делайте запрос на прямую к скрипту php ([пример](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html))

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
});
```

На сервер плагин передаст 44 параметра (`$_GET`) где вы можете найти, так же, информацию о смещении - `start` и `length`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT $start,$length
```

Но вам нужно правильно оформить ответ и так же вернуть помимо строк, информацию о количестве всего данных в таблице, информацию о фильтрации и т.д. Всю информацию вы можете найти [здесь](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Answer (score 0):

А чем Datatables принципиально отличается от обычного html+css+js кода?

1. Получаем количество записей в таблице.
2. Разбиваем на группы и записываем в файл диапазоны записей для вывода на одной странице.
3. Для каждой группы создаем свою ссылку, которая определяет, какие данные из БД нам грузить при нажатии на нее. Как вы реализуете сам запрос ajax или обычный GET запрос - не имеет никакого значения.
4. Формируем страницу с последними загруженными данными и отображаем ее пользователю.