# Постраничная навигация MySQL в PHP с помощью AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii2

Люди помогите))

```
    private function AJAX_getLists() {
    if ( !isset( $this->access->connections ) ) $this->_sendAnswer( 'Нет прав на данное действие.' );
    $tableApi = "SELECT 
            tAPU.userAbout AS usab
            ,tAPI.function_name AS funam
            ,tAPI.user_id AS usid
            ,tAPI.tstamp AS tst
            FROM _api_connections AS tAPI INNER JOIN api_users AS tAPU ON tAPI.user_Id = tAPU.userId
            ORDER BY tAPI.tstamp DESC
          ";
    $tableApi = Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $tableApi )->queryAll();

    $vars = [
                    'tableApi' => $tableApi,
                    'access' => $this->access,
                ];
    $data = $this->render('ajax/getlists', $vars);
    $this->_sendAnswer($data,true);
}
```

Мне надо узнать сколько нужно страниц сделать для страничной навигации, если на каждой странице будет по 1000 записей, и сделать постраничную навигацию, уже много что перепробовал ни чего не помогает. Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать постраничный вывод из БД MySQL в Datatables?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460645/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-mysql-%d0%b2-datatables)

Answer (score 1):

Количество страниц можно определить так:

```
$records = count($tableApi);
$records_per_page = 1000;

$pages = floor($records / $records_per_page) + 1);
```

Записи для определенной страницей можно лимитировать либо через сам sql, либо в php:

```
$records = array_slice( $tableApi, $records_per_page * $page_number, $records_per_page);
```